# Any Difference between tensor product over integer numbers and rational numbers?

Tags: ring-theory, tensor-products

Are the following two rings isomorphic: $\mathbb{R}\otimes_\mathbb{Q}\mathbb{R}$  and $\mathbb{R}\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{R}$

I think they are isomorphic as $\mathbb{Z}$-modules. But as rings I have no idea how to aproach the problem. So any hint or comment would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A homomorphism of rings is an isomorphism of rings iff it's an isomorphism of abelian groups iff it's an isomorphism of sets. If you know that they're isomorphic as $\mathbb{Z}$-modules probably what you mean is that the natural map $\mathbb{R} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{R}$ is an isomorphism of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules (this is true more generally for any tensor product of $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces, and in particular $\mathbb{Q}$-algebras). This natural map is a ring homomorphism and hence a ring isomorphism.

Comment: By „a map of rings“, do you mean „a homomorphism of rings“? Because otherwise, the „iff it's an isomorphism of sets“ part seems very wrong.

Comment: @Lukas: yes, that's what I mean, I can edit to be more precise.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you. Based on what you said: Tensor product of two copies of Q (i.e., rational numbers) over Q are isomorphic to the tensor product of two copies of Q over the integer numbers as rings. (as Z-modules both are isomorphic to Q). Am I right?

Comment: @Mikefr: yes, that's right.